# Can create extended Field classes for Django Models introduce unexpected problems?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm starting a Django project and in my early design I'm thinking about extending the model's fields classes to add a new optional attribute `belongs_to`. It will be a list of elements that later would serve the purpose of filtering the object attributes.

Example:

```
# models.py

class CustomCharField(models.CharField):
    def __init__(self, belongs_to: list=list(), *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.belongs_to = belongs_to


class ModeloTest(models.Model):
    attr1 = CustomCharField(max_length=20, belongs_to=list(('type1', 'type2')))
    attr2 = CustomCharField(max_length=10)
    attr3 = CustomCharField(max_length=10, belongs_to=list(('type1',)))
    attr4 = CustomCharField(max_length=10, belongs_to=list(('type2', 'type3')))
    attr5 = CustomCharField(max_length=10, belongs_to=list(('type4')))
    attr6 = CustomCharField(max_length=10, belongs_to=list(('type3',)))
    
    def fields_belongs_to(self, search_element):
        # 'id' Field is not Custom, doesn't have or need 'belongs_to' and can be ignored
        fields = [field for field in self._meta.fields if field.name != 'id']
        filtered_fields = [field for field in fields if search_element in field.belongs_to]
        output = dict()
        for field in filtered_fields:
            output[field.name] = getattr(self, field.name)
        return output
```

```
# views.py

def main_view(request):
    
    m = ModeloTest.objects.first()
    context = {
        'type1': m.fields_belongs_to('type1'),
    }
    return render(request, 'placeholder/main.html', context)
```

With this design I can organize and classify fields in the Model and with the `object.fields_belongs_to(search_element)` method I get a dict of the Fields that belong to the type selected in search_element.

If in the future I add a new Field in the Model, I just need to add the arg `belongs_to` and it will appear whenever I use the `fields_belongs_to` method without having to reflect the addition anywhere else.

My questions are:

- Is there a built-in functionality that I'm not seeing in the Field class that does what I'm trying to accomplish here?
- And the **main question**: Could there be unexpected problems for using a custom class for Fields, even if inheriting from them? Maybe Django checks somewhere the field type and errors appear because this is a `CustomCharField` and not a `models.CharField`, or on the contrary no side effects will appear because this is just a normal `CharField` with a new attribute that the base funcionality in Django just ignores and everything goes exactly the same.

Thanks a lot for taking the time to read my question!